# How do I identify nan values in pandas data frame where all variables are categorical?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with all categorical variables and when I apply
      `df.isnull().sum(axis=0)`.  or even `df.isna` gives 0. 
to get all the nans column wise I get an output which shows 0 for all columns however I can see many missing values when I do `df.head(50)`. I think it is because it is obj types it is not getting identified. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Can you come up with a [MCVE]?

Comment: Are your missing values actually `numpy.nan` or None values and not just the text 'nan' or ' missing'

Comment: well I have a Data frame which has types = obj for all columns and some of the values in columns is "nan" I want to identify them and get a count of how many such values exist in each column. when I do any kind of .isnull() or .isna() it shows 0 records hence I assume its text 'nan' @Dillon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the values are text I can get it like this :

```
df[df['PRODUCT_NO'].str.contains("nan")]
df=df[df.PRODUCT_NO.str.contains("nan") == False]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check `Null` values with the following code:

```
print(df.isnull().any())
```

Answer (score -4):

Do it this way:

```
df.isnull().values.sum()
```

Comment: already done this... the values were 'nan' in text as its categorical so this won't identify